# Is there any function analogous to mprotect in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

The [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) system call in Linux allows the calling program
to set regions of memory to read/execute-only, read-only (no execute),
execute-only, etc. 
Apparently it can be used only in userspace. 
Is there an analogous function in the Linux kernel
that would allow me to change memory page attributes in the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

```
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_ro(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_rw(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_x(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_nx(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
```